# how to iterate over array of jsons in Python

Tags: python, json

I have an array that looks like:

```
  item =   [{'name': 'first'}, {'name': 'second', 'something': 'something4'},  {'name': 'third', 'hu': 'g'}]
```

I want to write a function that given a key it will return the json that contains the key. For example: by for `first` it will return `{'name': 'first'}` for `third` it will return  `{'name': 'third', 'hu': 'g'}`

This is what I wrote so far

```
def func(obj, val_to_search , key_to_search):
    j = json.loads(item)
    for item in j:
        if j[key_to_search] = val_to_search
           return j

func(obj=item, val_to_search='first', key_to_search='name')
```

but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you show is not list of json, but list of dicts. Doesn't work is not very helpful description of a problem. Please, provide [mre]

Comment: You are using single = instead of == please check these typo mistakes before posting

Comment: @U12-Forward, there are number of errors in the snippet and I am not sure this is correct duplicate

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what you want to do? The description is about JSON and keys, the example about dicts and value, and the code about JSON and key-value *pairs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is already a Python object:

```
item = [{
    'name': 'first'
}, {
    'name': 'second',
    'something': 'something4'
}, {
    'name': 'third',
    'hu': 'g'
}]


def func(obj, val_to_search, key_to_search):
    for item in obj:
        if item[key_to_search] == val_to_search:
            return item


res = func(obj=item, val_to_search='first', key_to_search='name')
print(res)
```

Out:

```
{'name': 'first'}
```